# Using the `is` operator with Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, types, operators

I want to do something like this:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{
   SomeClass()
   {
        bool IsInterface = T is ISomeInterface;
   }
}
```

What is the best way for something like this?

Note: I am not looking to constrain `T` with a `where`, but I would like my code to be aware of what types of interfaces `T` implements. I would prefer that I don't have to construct a `T`.

Comment: If you're checking types in a generic method/class, IMO something is wrong.

Comment: I don't want to have 3 separate descendants of SomeClass. I want some class to certain things depending if `T` has something.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think you can use the `is` operator for this. But you can use IsAssignableFrom:

```
bool IsInterface = typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 9):

**should use following instead**

```
 bool IsInterface = typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

**is operator**

`is` operator is used to check whether the `run-time type` of an object 
is `compatible` with a given `type`.

An expression where the use of `is` conforms to the syntax, evaluates to true, if both of the following conditions are met:

- expression is not null.
- expression can be cast to type. That
  is, a cast expression of the form
  (type)(expression) will complete
  without throwing an exception. For
  more information, see [**7.6.6 Cast
  expressions.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691370(VS.71).aspx)

---

**References**

- [**Does a Type Implement an Interface?**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DoesATypeImplementAnInterface.aspx)
- [**is operator**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx):

```
  class SomeClass<T>
  {
     SomeClass()
     {
        bool IsIComparable = typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
bool IsInterface = typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you can do it:

```
bool IsInterface = typeof(ISomeInterface).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing something like

```
Type Ttype = typeof(T);
```

That will give you the full power of the Type class, which has functions like "FindInterfaces".